# Issue involving Silverlight on Windows 10

Tags: silverlight, microsoft-edge

After installing Windows 10 and then going to my website, that uses Silverlight, I find that Microsoft Edge does not support Silverlight.  Has Microsoft killed Silverlight?  Is there any way to run Silverlight in some add-in that will run in Edge?  I have a lot of code invested in Silverlight. Is my only option to rewrite all of my apps?  In What?  HTML 5 and javascript?

I can't seem to install IE 11 on windows 10.

Comment: What do you mean by 'Install IE11 on Windows 10'?   It should already be installed - it is for me.  You might also like to know that Google Chrome is dropping support for Silverlight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Has Microsoft killed Silverlight?

**They have killed it for Edge.** While you can keep using it in IE 11 and other out-of-browser apps, Microsoft is really discouraging it.

> Is there any way to run Silverlight in some add-in that will run in Edge? ... I can't seem to install IE 11 on windows 10.

Within Edge, click the `...` in the top right corner. Choose **Open with Internet Explorer.**

[image: Open with Internet Explorer]

> Is my only option to rewrite all of my apps? In What? HTML 5 and javascript?

In the short term, you could encourage users to click on Open with Internet Explorer. In the long term it's HTML5 and JavaScript including DASH, MSE, CENC, and EME.

- **DASH**. Dynamic Adaptive Streaming over HTTP.
- **MSE**. Media Source Extensions.
- **CENC**. Common Encryption.
- **EME**. Encrypted Media Extensions.

## References

- http://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2015/07/02/moving-to-html5-premium-media/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/DASH_Adaptive_Streaming_for_HTML_5_Video
- http://www.w3.org/TR/media-source/
- http://docs.unified-streaming.com/documentation/drm/common-encryption.html
- http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eme/basics/

Comment: Thanks for he answer, Shaun.  What a shame.  The children who work at Microsoft, of course, don't remember how we used to laugh at Netscape Javascript back when it was introduced in 95.  From C# to Javascript.  My God.